# Regex/PHP Remove everything before first letter

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all characters before the first letter...
How do I search for the position of the first occurance of [a-z] & [A-Z].

```
$test = "1234 123423-34 This is a test";

$string = preg_replace('/REGEX/', "", $test);
echo $string;
```

Should output:
This is a test

Comment: search for [`^[^a-zA-Z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/GDEdhk/1) and replace it with an empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a negated character class with a leading anchor.

```
^[^A-Za-z]+
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/149aDt/1

PHP Demo: https://3v4l.org/7m6RZ

```
$test = "1234 123423-34 This is a test";
echo preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $test);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$test = "1234 123423-34 This is a test";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($test);$i++){
    if(!ctype_alpha($test[$i])){
        $test[$i] = '';
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to chris85 answer, if you want to deal with unicode characters:

```
$str = '123 μεγάλο τριχωτό της γάτας';
$result = preg_replace('~\PL+~Au', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strcspn`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) function to return the length of the initial string segment which does NOT matching any of the given characters, e.g.:

```
$position = strcspn($test, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

This does not account for Unicode letters.

Also note that you can accomplish your task (replacement) with regular expressions, *without the need to determine this position* (see the other answer).